# call javascript function for a specific wordpress page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I need to create a string dynamically inside a wordpress site page, I am thinking a javascript function that needs to take a number as a parameter and return a string in form '[Site User]_[date( yyyy-mm-dd )]. The date would be current date - the number of days given in the parameter.

I attempted to add a function into the function.php file, but I ended up crashing the whole website as a result of my efforts.

What I need is either a trustworthy (as in semi-secure) plugin to run in page javascript, or a method to get that string when I call.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey what you need to do is:

Just get the page id first i.e

```
$id = get_the_ID();
```

Now see the page id of the page for which you want to ass teh Javascript function.

Now add all the codes in your `header.php` file:

A typical could be something like the below:

```
<?php

$id = get_the_ID();

if($id==your_pageid)
{
?>
<script>

function yourFunction()
{

//Run your codes here

}

</script>

<?php 

}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to check this recently but that is what I needed.

Comment: NP, you are most welcome!!